# How to feed WebBrowser control and manipulate the HTML document?

Tags: c#, html, browser, dom

Good day

I have question about displaying html documents in a windows forms applications. App that I'm working on should display information from the

database in the html format. I will try to describe actions that I have taken (and which failed):

1) I tried to load "virtual" html page that exists only in memory and dynamically change it's parameters (webbMain is a WebBrowser control):

```
public static string CreateBookHtml()
{
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 //Declaration
 sb.AppendLine(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>");
 sb.AppendLine(@"<?xml-stylesheet type=""text/css"" href=""style.css""?>");
 sb.AppendLine(@"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"" 
                    ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"">");
 sb.AppendLine(@"<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" xml:lang=""en"">"); 

 //Head
 sb.AppendLine(@"<head>");
 sb.AppendLine(@"<title>Exemplary document</title>");
 sb.AppendLine(@"<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""application/xhtml+xml; 
                                                                charset=utf-8""/   >");
 sb.AppendLine(@"</head>");

 //Body
 sb.AppendLine(@"<body>");
 sb.AppendLine(@"<p id=""paragraph"">Example.</p>");
 sb.AppendLine(@"</body>");
 sb.AppendLine(@"</html>");

 return sb.ToString();
}
```

void LoadBrowser()
    {
    this.webbMain.Navigate("about:blank");
    this.webbMain.DocumentText = CreateBookHtml();
    HtmlDocument doc = this.webbMain.Document;
    }

This failed, because doc.Body is null, and doc.getElementById("paragraph") returns null too. So I cannot change paragraph InnerText property.

Furthermore, this.webbMain.DocumentText is "\0"...

2) I tried to create html file in specified folder, load it to the WebBrowser and then change its parameters. Html is the same as created by

CreateBookHtml() method:

```
private void LoadBrowser()
        {
            this.webbMain.Navigate("HTML\\BookPage.html"));             
            HtmlDocument doc = this.webbMain.Document;
        }
```

This time this.webbMain.DocumentText contains Html data read from the file, but doc.Body returns null again, and I still cannot take element using

getByElementId() method. Of course, when I have text, I would try regex to get specified fields, or maybe do other tricks to achieve a goal, but I wonder - is there simply way to mainipulate html? For me, ideal way would be to create HTML text in memory, load it into the WebBrowser control, and then dynamically change its parameters using IDs. Is it possible? Thanks for the answers in advance, best regards,

Paweł

Comment: There is no NavigateToString method of the WebBrowser control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've worked some time ago with the WebControl and like you wanted to load a html from memory but have the same problem, body being null. After some investigation, I noticed that the Navigate and NavigateToString methods work asynchronously, so it needs a little time for the control to load the document, the document is not available right after the call to Navigate. So i did something like (wbChat is the WebBrowser control):

```
wbChat.NavigateToString("<html><body><div>first line</div></body><html>");

DoEvents();
```

where DoEvents() is implemeted as:

```
[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
public void DoEvents()
{
    DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}
```

and it worked for me, after the DoEvents call, I could obtain a non-null body:

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)wbChat.Document;

mshtml.HTMLDivElement div = (mshtml.HTMLDivElement)doc2.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "some text";
mshtml.HTMLBodyClass body = (mshtml.HTMLBodyClass)doc2.body;

if (body != null)
{
    body.appendChild((mshtml.IHTMLDOMNode)div);

    body.scrollTop = body.scrollHeight;
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("body is still null");
```

I don't know if this is the **right** way of doing this, but it fixed the problem for me, maybe it helps you too.

Later Edit:

```
public object ExitFrame(object f)
{
    ((DispatcherFrame)f).Continue = false;
    return null;
}
```

The DoEvents method is necessary on WPF. For System.Windows.Forms one can use Application.DoEvents().

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer. I'd like to add something to it. First, there should be ExitFrame method body. It looks like: ExitFrame(object f){((DispatcherFrame)f).Continue = false;return null;}. Second, we have to add two assemblies to the solution: WindowsBase.dll and Microsoft.mshtml.dll. Third: I couldn't find NavigateToString method in WebBrowser. Most important is, that your solution works (looks awful, but works :)), and I'm writing above only for other readers. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've forgot to add the ExitFrame method and to mention about the assemblies, I will edit the answer so that the code will be more visible. Regarding the NavigateToString - I was actually using the WPF version of the WebBrowser control which actually has this method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx ) though this is strange, because I suspect it is a wrapper around the native control, just like the WebBrowser from System.Windows.Forms. I'm not happy either with how this looks, but sometimes you just don't have what to do...

Comment: Just on the side note of things HTMLBodyClass might give compilation error for .net version > 4 rather use the interface declaration HTMLBody.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do the same thing is:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body>blabla<hr/>yadayada</body></html>";
```

this works without any extra initialization